# Why does adding this field make my query run slow?

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query below runs in less than a second if I take off one field from the select list -- the last one, `att`.  But having it there causes the query to take over a minute.  Any thoughts?  Note that the subquery inside the left join runs fast on its own.

```
select p.person_id, cfm.family_id, p.nick_name, p.last_name, s.lookup_value as group_role, gm.active, g.group_id, g.group_name, 
g.active as group_active, tg.category, gc.cluster_name, coalesce(a.attendance,0) as att --this field is the culprit
from smgp_group g
join smgp_group_cluster gc on g.group_cluster_id = gc.group_cluster_id
join smgp_member gm on g.group_id = gm.group_id
join core_person p on gm.person_id = p.person_id
join core_family_member cfm on p.person_id = cfm.person_id
join core_lookup s on gm.role_luid = s.lookup_id
join @target_groups tg on g.group_id = tg.group_id
left join (
  select at.person_id, goc.group_id, count(at.attended) as attendance from core_occurrence_attendance at
  join core_occurrence o on at.occurrence_id = o.occurrence_id
  join smgp_group_occurrence goc on o.occurrence_id = goc.occurrence_id
  where goc.group_id in (select group_id from @target_groups)
  and o.occurrence_start_time between @start_date and @end_date
  group by at.person_id, goc.group_id
) a on p.person_id = a.person_id and g.group_id = a.group_id
where tg.category = 'adults' or (tg.category = 'kids' and s.lookup_value in ('Leader-Teacher','Assistant Leader'))
```

Comment: Take a look at the execution plan for both with and without. It will tell you why

Comment: Probably because without `att` the database doesn't bother running the subquery at all - nothing uses it, and a left join doesnt restrict the existing found rows any, so it's pointless performing the subquery if it can neither add anything (the results are unused, the subquery is grouped and wont cause cartesian product of an existing resultset) or take it away (a table that is left joined can never reduce the existing row count)

Comment: SQL Server.  I have no experience with execution plans, and so I may just not understand them well enough.  But I tried to look at the estimated plan with and without the field and couldn't pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @Caius Jard that makes sense.

Comment: It would be interesting to note: does the subquery run slowly in isloation, does the same performance hit occur if it is INNER joined instead (but no attempt to use a value from it in the select list), does performance also suffer if it's left joined but doesn't contain a group by... DB optimizers can sometimes go pretty far in rewriting a query. All in, if you want to use the result, you're going to have to improve the performance of teh subquery. Possibly better asked as another question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below runs in 3 seconds and resolved the problem.  Thanks.

```
select at.person_id, goc.group_id, count(at.attended) as attendance 
into #a
from core_occurrence_attendance at
join core_occurrence o on at.occurrence_id = o.occurrence_id
join smgp_group_occurrence goc on o.occurrence_id = goc.occurrence_id
where goc.group_id in (select group_id from @target_groups)
and o.occurrence_start_time between @start_date and @end_date
group by at.person_id, goc.group_id 

select p.person_id, cfm.family_id, p.nick_name, p.last_name, s.lookup_value as group_role, gm.active, g.group_id, g.group_name, 
g.active as group_active, tg.category, gc.cluster_name, coalesce(#a.attendance,0) as att--, --this field is the culprit
from smgp_group g
join smgp_group_cluster gc on g.group_cluster_id = gc.group_cluster_id
join smgp_member gm on g.group_id = gm.group_id
join core_person p on gm.person_id = p.person_id
join core_family_member cfm on p.person_id = cfm.person_id
join core_lookup s on gm.role_luid = s.lookup_id
join @target_groups tg on g.group_id = tg.group_id
left join #a on p.person_id = #a.person_id and g.group_id = #a.group_id
where tg.category = 'adults' or (tg.category = 'kids' and s.lookup_value in ('Leader-Teacher','Assistant Leader'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following -

```
SELECT p.persON_id, cfm.family_id, p.nick_name, 
       p.last_name, s.lookup_value as group_role, 
       gm.active, g.group_id, g.group_name, 
       g.active as group_active, tg.cATegory, 
       gc.cluster_name, a.ATtendance 
  INTO #tempDataset
  FROM smgp_group g
  JOIN smgp_group_cluster gc 
    ON g.group_cluster_id = gc.group_cluster_id
  JOIN smgp_member gm 
    ON g.group_id = gm.group_id
  JOIN core_persON p 
    ON gm.persON_id = p.persON_id
  JOIN core_family_member cfm 
    ON p.persON_id = cfm.persON_id
  JOIN core_lookup s 
    ON gm.role_luid = s.lookup_id
  JOIN @target_groups tg 
    ON g.group_id = tg.group_id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT AT.persON_id, goc.group_id, count(AT.ATtended) as ATtendance FROM core_occurrence_ATtendance AT
               JOIN core_occurrence o 
                 ON AT.occurrence_id = o.occurrence_id
               JOIN smgp_group_occurrence goc 
                 ON o.occurrence_id = goc.occurrence_id
              WHERE goc.group_id IN (SELECT group_id 
                                       FROM @target_groups)
                                        AND o.occurrence_start_time BETWEEN @start_dATe AND @end_dATe
                                      GROUP BY AT.persON_id, goc.group_id) a 
    ON p.persON_id = a.persON_id 
   AND g.group_id = a.group_id
WHERE tg.cATegory = 'adults' or (tg.cATegory = 'kids' AND s.lookup_value IN ('Leader-Teacher','Assistant Leader'))

SELECT persON_id, 
       family_id, 
       nick_name, 
       last_name, 
       group_role, 
       active, 
       group_id, 
       group_name, 
       group_active, 
       cATegory, 
       cluster_name, 
       coalesce(ATtendance,0) AS ATT
  FROM #tempDataset
```

If that runs slowly, you can possibly add an index on the temp table, but I would try doing the above as a first step.

Comment: thanks, but for some reason that made it even slower.  I did find a different use of a temporary table that worked, though - I'll post that as the answer.

Comment: Nice one Roger!